# Average of buffer fails testcases

Tags: c

```
    /****************** Average ****************************
Find the average of the data in a variable length buffer 
The data in the buffer range from -127 to +127
Input: size is the number of elements in the buffer
       pt is a pointer to the buffer
Output: average of the data in the buffer
Error conditions: Return 0 if the buffer is empty.
Test cases
  size value buffer
   5,    {1,4,3,3,4}                  //Average=3
  10,    {-3,-10,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0}     //Average=-1
   5,    {-1,2,3,-3,4}                //Average=1
   7,    {-6,-9,-7,-8,-8,-9,-9}       //Average=-8
   0,    {}                           //Average=0
*/
int8_t Average(uint32_t size, const int8_t *pt){ 
    int32_t i, sum, average = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){                             //calculates sum of array
        sum+= *pt;
        (pt)++;
    }
    average = sum/size;

  return(average);  // change this line
}
```

I'm learning C so I apologize is my formatting looks weird. My code fails all of the testcases except for the empty buffer, where it returns 0; Is my setup for the `for` loop incorrect? Can anyone spot anything wrong off the bat with my code? Thanks.

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

Thank you for the comments! I've read them all and have implemented changes in my code. The fix that made all testcases work was to declare another variable, `size1`, and do:

`int32_t size1 = size;`.

Some other things that I changed were to set the condition code in the `for` loop to be:

`i < size`
in addition to declaring each value in its own statement. Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: You initialized `average`, but not `sum`.

Comment: Your loop will iterate size+1 times

Comment: `<=` is wrong; must be `<`.  There should be checked for `size != 0` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the variable **sum to 0** , because in the first definition, sum has an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below modified codes. Also see my comments

```
int8_t Average(uint32_t size, const int8_t *pt){ 
    if(size <= 0)
      return 0;// size can not be less than or equal to zero also we can avoid divide by 0 issue 
    int32_t i, sum = 0, average = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ //calculates sum of array also it should not be i<=size because we use index from 0 not from 1
       sum+= *pt;
       pt++;// no need of bracket
    }
     average = sum/size;

  return average;  // change this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your end condition is wrong, it's not "i <= size" but "i < size"